# Problems with creating a list in C#

Tags: .net

I am a beginner in C#. I would like to create a list of different strings as follows:

```
public List<string> NombreEtiquetas = new List<string>();
NombreEtiquetas.Add("refmotor");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("refinducido");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("tiporeducccion");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("reltransmision");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("tiporeduccion");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("parresidual");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("rinducido");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("linducido");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("constpar");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("constvel");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("restermicas");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("captermica");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("mecanicas");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("acero");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("ohmicas");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("eficiencia");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("vel");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("tn");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("in");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("lmt");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("ff");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("ar");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("rcp");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("nc");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("tipohilo");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("vacio");
NombreEtiquetas.Add("bloqueo");
```

The issue comes in Visual Studio by using the add method. It seems the underlined part is below the string. It seems it does not like the string format somehow. It comaplains with code error CS1519 for example. Any help?

Comment: The keyword `public` tells me you're declaring a field of a class, which is fine. You cannot put statements at the class level, like all those calls to the Add method, you will have to put those inside a method. So move all those add-statements into a method and call the method.

Comment: A different approach would be to use the collection initializer and instead declare the list as `public List<string> NombreEtiquetas = new List<string>() { "refmotor", "refinducido", ... };`, then you don't need the add-statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing a field or property, then collection initializer syntax is your friend, since you can't use multi-line statements:

```cs
public List<string> NombreEtiquetas = new List<string> {
    "refmotor",
    // ...
    "bloqueo"
};
```

Note also that public fields are a bad idea; usually you'd want a *property*:

```cs
public List<string> NombreEtiquetas {get;} = new List<string> {
    "refmotor",
    // ...
    "bloqueo"
};
```